# How to create a shortcode in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, keyboard-shortcuts

**Correct me if i'm using any wrong term (I don't know exactly what this feature is called)**

Is there any Option/Plugin for creating my own short code for java in Eclipse IDE

Just like these short-code represent

```
syso --> System.out.println();


syse --> System.error.println();


fori --> for(int i=0;i<args.length;i++){}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are 'Templates'.

You can create your own in 'Preferences > Java > Editor > Templates'

Comment: Hi can you help me to solve this problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27015236/extract-api-from-class

Answer (score 2):

Yes, It is possible with eclipse custom templates.

Open `Window -> Preferences` and type `Templates` into the search box.

[image]

Refer this [official help guide](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.cdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Fcdt_t_add_codetemp.htm) to understand easily.