# Extract interfaces from a class

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, interface, refactoring

I want to generate interface from my model class in eclipse/intelij

generating from single class is quite easy

**Right click --> Refactor --> generate interface**

but the problem is i have 100's of classes.

is there any tool/plugin or script which can generate multiple interface in 1 go from a single package.
or any maven plugin to do so.

http://mojo.codehaus.org/gwt-maven-plugin/generateAsync-mojo.html

here i got a plugin but it generate `generateAsync`

Answer (score 1):

Probably fastest way is write own simple application to do this operation.

Comment: just little bit guide me how to do so

Comment: there is what i got so far https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6141?pr=idea http://www.dvteclipse.com/documentation/sv/Writing_a_Refactoring_Script.html

Comment: For example create java console app to read class files as text, parse and generate interface files using FileUtils.listFiles, FileUtils.readLines

Comment: currently implementing this way but looking for some already existed plugin http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1456930/how-do-i-read-all-classes-from-a-java-package-in-the-classpath